# RESTful API URL not-included subresources

Tags: rest, url

We are designing a messaging system API.
There are 2 entities: `Channels` which contain `Subscribers` which can be added or removed at when necessary.

We need to provide API URLs to retrieve 2 lists of subscribers in relation to a specific channel:

1. `../channels/{id}/subscribers` - returns the list of subscribers who are subscribed to this particular channel.
2. `../channels/{id}/subscribers/unsubscribed` - returns the list of subscribers that are not subscribed to this channel - a user can select from this list new subscribers to add to the channel.

Are there better URL patterns to achieve the same results?

In other words - how to structure URLs which represent a subresource that is not attached to the specified parent?

Comment: IMHO, if a sub-resource does not belong to a resource, it cannot be considered a sub-resource. So, you could assume it's a main resource and try something as following: `/subscribers?channel=1&status=unsubscribed`. If `subscribers` does not sound well as a root resource, try renaming it to `customers` or `users`, for example.

Comment: @cássio-mazzochi-molin, the relationship between these 2 entities is many-to-many, so there is a `/subscribers` subresource, but the second url denotes a "negation" the first one - so we thought it should maintain the pattern, however the relationship is as you say - it may not be considered as a sub-resource. Therefore we cannot find good argumentation for either approach.

Comment: I think the key here is **keeping your hierarchy consistent**. When talking about sub-resources, we are talking about a *hierarchy* and the URL should express it. 
*If the sub-resource does not belong to the main resource, it cannot be considered a sub-resource*. So, you could assume `/subscribers` is a main resource and have a query string to filter this main resource according to your needs.